# Launch tmux with a command in the background without stopping said command when tmux stop running

Tags: bash, shell, tmux

So, I want to launch a shell command through tmux, but in the background and detaching from said tmux session...so I do it like so:

```bsh
tmux new-session -A -s myprogramsession \; send -t myprogramsession "nohup /usr/bin/myscript.sh &>/dev/null &" ENTER \; detach -s myprogramsession
```

This works. But now, if I want to make tmux stop once it detached from the aforementioned session, I would need to either do:

this:

```bsh
tmux new-session -A -s myprogramsession \; send -t myprogramsession "nohup /usr/bin/myscript.sh &>/dev/null &" ENTER \; detach -s myprogramsession \; kill-session -t myprogramsession
```

or this:

```bsh
tmux new-session -A -s myprogramsession \; send -t myprogramsession "nohup /usr/bin/myscript.sh &>/dev/null &" ENTER \; detach -s myprogramsession && pkill tmux
```

While both methods (one using `pkill` and `kill-session` from `tmux`) seems to work on first glance, I noticed both prevent the process/script launched through `nohup` from *staying* in the background, compared to the first attempt which manage to do so (minus for the part about stopping `tmux`).

How could I make `tmux` (based on the above examples) launch a shell command on a session (in the background), detach it, then stop `tmux` completely while the shell command is still running in the background?

P.S.: I did check through [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269805/how-can-i-detach-a-process-from-a-bash-script) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31902929/how-to-write-a-shell-script-that-starts-tmux-session-and-then-runs-a-ruby-scrip) post, but failed to find a solution there.

Comment: What do you need `tmux` for? To kill it right away? What's the point?

Comment: I need it because some programs sometimes (here I'm running an external program in the script.sh following the example) do not work even with nohup, depending on whether it's run in the terminal or in the background/through a few layer of scripts...I could have posted a question about this behavior to make sure why it happened, but by the time I thought of doing so, I found a method that worked (using tmux + nohup) so I ended up not doing that :) @KamilMaciorowski

Comment: You may consider `run-shell` as a replacement of `send-keys`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looked easier than I thought:

```bsh
tmux new-session -A -s myprogramsession \; send -t myprogramsession "nohup /usr/bin/myscript.sh &>/dev/null &" ENTER \; detach -s myprogramsession && sleep 1 && pkill tmux
```

This work if a `sleep` is added before `pkill` comes in. Probably not the best solution however.